# List of ticker-symbols of European countries

Tags: equities, data

To download the European countries' equity (stocks) data from CRSP database, I need individual stocks ticker symbols. Can anyone help me regarding how can I get the list of ticker-symbols of European countries stocks? I can manage to download ticker symbols of NASDAC, AMEX, and NYSE stocks from this link:

https://www.kaggle.com/qks1lver/amex-nyse-nasdaq-stock-histories

Comment: Are you comfortable using a little Python?

Comment: I am not but I can ask my friend. @amdopt

Answer (score 3):

Have your friend give this Python library a try for you: [pytickersymbols](https://pypi.org/project/pytickersymbols/).  It specifically exists to return ticker symbols.  I have not used it extensively-only a brief test using the code below (which is taken from their documentation).  The symbols come from Yahoo and Google finance. If you have interest in what is going on under the hood, this is the GitHub repo: [pytickersymbols GitHub repo](https://github.com/portfolioplus/pytickersymbols)

```
from pytickersymbols import PyTickerSymbols

stock_data = PyTickerSymbols()
countries = stock_data.get_all_countries()
indices = stock_data.get_all_indices()
industries = stock_data.get_all_industries()
```

After running that code, you can view the tickers like this:

```
print(list(countries))
print(list(indices))
print(list(industries))
```

You can export the symbols to a `.csv` or `.xlsx` file as well if you need to work with them outside of Python.  This is quite easy to do and shouldn't take your friend more than a few minutes of their time.  There are also slight variations that allow you to call for specific countries in case you don't want a list of all stocks.  You can find that info in the documentation in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have a database that covers all 70,000 stocks worldwide. You can download the European portion from the original table hosted on this [Public Domain](https://public.acho.io/embed/9bffe75f11a5a99349359c98c74b9b0ba41cf563b351ffbb7ecc19614706f827861e5171a35b6f8296aa1d43a7558cfb978ae74ac969094d1c991bf7d8c8ca9f). The tickers comply to Yahoo Finance's version.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of [global stock tickers](https://public.acho.io/embed/9bffe75f11a5a99349359c98c74b9b0ba41cf563b351ffbb7ecc19614706f827861e5171a35b6f8296aa1d43a7558cfb978ae74ac969094d1c991bf7d8c8ca9f) from UniBit. It contains around 72k tickers from 49 stock exchanges. It’s updated on a monthly basis. Newer IPOs, SPACs, and M&As will be updated. The stock symbols comply with Yahoo’s ticker version.